# PowerBI - Response Header reading

Tags: header, powerbi, response

We are trying to hit rest api using Power-BI, and we want to read the response header (x-signature) that we receive in the response from rest call. Can anyone help with this or how can we achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to solve that? I am also trying to obtain the XSRF-TOKEN or the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You case use `Value.Metadata` to retrieve additional information about your API request.

For example, using this free Weather API `7timer.info`, you can apply `Value.Metadata` just after using `Web.Contents`, as the code below shows.

```
let
    Response = Web.Contents("http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json"),
    Mt = Value.Metadata(Response)

in
    Mt[Headers]
```

### Output

The output will retrieve a set of records, in this case is just one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Angelo, but I need to read the header from the response, for example in the response we are getting a header named x-value. So I need to read the value of the response header.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, in fact `Web.Contents` is the response. I have change the name to the variable to make more sense, but is the same as before in terms of code. So the headers display here are the response headers.

Comment: Does this answer solve your question? If it does please mark it as a solution.

Comment: Hey Angelo, I was not able to achieve the expected result. As the Value.MetaData() is not reading the header from the response.

Comment: It does, the problem could be that Power BI does not retrieve all headers. But I've tested with Postman, and the result in the answer is from the response headers.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but in my case, I had a custom header and I was not able to read it.

Comment: were you able to solve that? I am also trying to obtain the XSRF-TOKEN or the cookies.

Comment: "The headers of the HTTP response are available as metadata on the binary result. Outside of a custom data connector context, only a subset of response headers is available (for security reasons)." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents

Custom headers are returned using an API in Postman but they are not returned in PowerBI.

Using web.headers instead does not allow you to specify 'content' hence you cannot make a POST/PUT and get the necessary headers either.